# android license checking PreferenceObfuscator getString catches ValidationException

Tags: android, encryption

I am implementing Android license checking and am currently testing using an unmodified copy of com.google.android.vending.licensing -- I know that it will need to be extensively modified to keep it secure.

I'm invoking the checking in the standard way:

```
private void checkLicence()
{
    if (licenseChecker == null)
    {
        licenseCheckerCallback = new Callbacks();
        licenseChecker = new LicenseChecker
        (
            this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this, new AESObfuscator(SALT, packageName, id)), pubKey
        );
    }
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    licenseChecker.checkAccess(licenseCheckerCallback);
}
```

The first time the app is started APKExpansionPolicy is given the default values by PreferenceObfuscator.getString because the preferences have yet to be saved.

The second time the app is run, values have been saved via PreferenceObfuscator.putString, but when APKExpansionPolicy calls getString to retrieve them, getString picks up a ValidationException thrown by AESObfuscator.unobfuscate when it caught a BadPaddingException.

getMessage for the BadPaddingException gave:

```
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

The result of the ValidationException is that PreferenceObfuscator.getString returns the default value, rather than the saved one.

I checked, and the string retrieved from the shared preference by PreferenceObfuscator.getString is the same encrypted string that was saved there by putString, including the same number of "=" signs at the end.

Why am I hitting this problem with vanilla library code?

Answer (score 0):

It was the way I was constructing SALT. rather than just an array literal, I had put in a way that i thought would always set the same values, but had put an error in that code.

Comment: The human mind is a wonderful thing. I spend hours trying to work out an answer and fail. Then I go to sleep and in the morning I wake up knowing the correct answer.